# Function for returning a wallet balance

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, wallet

I am trying to create a function that returns the balance of my sepolia testnet metamask wallet.

I wrote this function:

```
    function getBalance() external view onlyOwner returns (uint256) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }
```

but it returns 0 all the time.
Note that my smart contract is already connected to my metamask wallet and other functions are working good.

Answer (score 1):

`address(this)` returns the address of the contract.

Address of whoever executes the function is `msg.sender`. So in this case: `return msg.sender.balance;`

Few notes:

- `msg.sender` reflects whoever executes the function. It might be the end user, it might be some other contract that calls this function.
- Your function has the `view` modifier, which makes it read-only. Some apps (e.g. Etherscan without connected MetaMask wallet) might fallback to making the call from the zero address (`msg.sender == address(0)`) if they don't know the actual caller address.
- Your function has the `onlyOwner` modifier. Assuming it's from the OpenZeppelin Ownable library, the function reverts and doesn't return any value (not even zero) if it's not called from the `owner` address.